# Wrap text in grid

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid with a bound field. I have set `Item_style-wrap=true`.
But still it is NOT wrapping the data for me. What could be the issue?

Grid code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Reason" 
                HeaderText="Reason For Request" 
                ItemStyle-Wrap="true" 
                ItemStyle-Width="10%" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:BoundField>
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="true" />
        <ItemStyle Wrap="true" />
</asp:BoundField>
```